# "Choose Your Own Adventure" book, medieval fantasy and pet crow, bizarre possible ending implied to have been a dream

Tags: story-identification, books, choose-your-own-adventure

This was in the school library when I was in 3rd or 4th grade, so around 1992 or 1993 (the elementary had its own library), though the reading level was above my head at the time. I remember the "armour" spelling, the setting was unusually dark and gritty, it seemed like the book really shouldn't have been in the library there. The person you were 'playing' as had more of a fleshed out background.  Looking for this again I found the *Lone Wolf* (not the manga) CYOA and *Fighting Fantasy* but it isn't either one of those.

You had a friend who was a man with a pet crow I believe or it was you yourself whp had a pet raven or crow.

One of the endings that still sticks in my mind is one where you sit in front of a campfire at night, after you make a 'wrong choice' and everything you've witnessed up until this point happens to have been a dream or is vaguely implied as such.

Comment: I know you said it wasn't Fighting Fantasy, but one of the FF books (Magehunter) did have a bizarre, fourth-wall-warping ending where you went into a dream while listening to a story, and that story then merged with the book's story. It also has a raven in it.

Comment: "Blood Sword" book 2 ("The Kingdom of Wyrd") has a section where you can acquire a pet raven (see https://forum.rpg.net/index.php?threads/lets-play-the-battlepits-of-karth.828024/page-39) and a Big Bad who invades people's dreams to kill them.

Comment: Possibly one of the Grailquest books? I haven't read all of them, but you do have a more fleshed out backstory and since they're British armour would be spelled armour.

Comment: "The Kingdom of Wyrd" as referenced in @AJM-Reinstate-Monica's comment does have quite a few scenes where the adventuring party camp out for the night (including making campfires.) During their sleep, I think they had to play out mini-adventures and fight enemies in their dreams. There was a bit where you had to consciously try to wake up from a dream while being attacked by zombies.

Comment: very late reply but looking at some of these, Magehunter looks vaguely familiar thanks so much

Comment: @Ryft That's cool - and https://fightingfantazine.proboards.com/thread/281/57-magehunter-solution does mention an encounter with a raven in that book.